# Why doesn't Team Explorer shows dll files in "Detected Changes"?

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I have added two files to a folder that is under solution, but not in the solution tree (it is in a packages folder):

`a.dll`
`a.dll.txt`

When I go to "Detected Changes" on Team Explorer - Pending Changes, in the list I see `a.dll.txt` but `a.dll` file is not there.

I did check all relevant `.tfignore` files to make sure `.dll`s are not excluded.

Question is: what is filtering out dll files from detected changes?

Answer (score 1):

In previous versions you controlled this via a registry setting, i'm not sure it applies to this but it may be a good starting point.

http://www.ewaldhofman.nl/post/2009/08/02/Change-the-file-masks-that-are-excluded-by-Source-Control.aspx

as you mentioned tfs 2012 has the idea of .tfignore files for local workspaces (.tpignore for server workspaces) , you can include automatically excluded files by adding in inverse rules like

!*.dll

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tfs/ms245454%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#tfignore